# Why does Java crypto AES pad my plaintext message which is exactly 16bytes?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

For example, if a message is 16-byte long:
String message = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
byte[] plaintext = message.getBytes();//plaintext.length = 16

the output cyphtertext would be 32-byte long, which indicates there are 2 blocks here, and the second block has been padded.

Whereas, if a message is 15-byte long or shorter:
String message = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
byte[] plaintext = message.getBytes();//plaintext.length = 15

the output cyphertext would also be 16-byte long.

Since AES's block is 16-byte long, why 16-byte plaintext message would be divided into two blocks and be padded?

Thanks！

Comment: Can you show your code?  You might have a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends on the encryption *mode*. Some modes do not require padding at all, but the modes that require padding do require that messages of a multiple of the block length include an additional block full of padding bytes, otherwise it becomes ambiguous if the data is padded or not.

Since *some* messages will be padded, the algorithm will *always* look at the last bytes and interpret them as padding information. So *all* messages must be padded, even those that are of a suitable length in the first place.

For example, if your padding scheme adds bytes which values is the number of missing bytes to fill the block, and your message ends with `01` or `02 02`, `03 03 03`, etc. You wouldn't know if it's padding or data.

Comment: Thanks so much. So, if the message is 15-byte long, the padding would be 01, if the message is 14-byte long, the padding would be 02 02, if the message is 16-byte long, the algorithm would create another block which itself is a padding and it would be 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10. Do I understand it right?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Note however that it's just one particular padding scheme, known as PKCS#7, probably the most used, but there are others. In any case a full dummy block will be added if the plaintext is a multiple of the block length.